# Texture2D SetData<T>(T[], Int32, Int32) AccessViolationException

Tags: c#, .net, xna

I am trying to set the data of a Texture2D using `SetData<T>(T[], Int32, Int32)` but no matter what I put as the variables, I always get

> AccessViolationException: Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.

I have tried using `Microsoft.Xna.Color[]` and `byte[]` for T, but the same error occurs. `SetData<T>(T[])` works without error, but I would like to improve performance by using `SetData<T>(T[], Int32, Int32)` instead.

I am using Visual Studio 2013 with .NET 4.5.1 and monogame.

Answer (score 1):

Before calling SetData(), you need:

```
GraphicsDevice.Textures[0] = null;
```

To modify parts of the texture, use the Rectangle overload of the SetData().

```
SetData<T>(int mipmapLevel, Rectangle? rect, Color[] data, int startIndex, int elementCount)
```

Use the rectangle to target which pixels to change, pass `0` for `startIndex` and `elementCount` is `rect.Width * rect.Height`

Answer (score 0):

Let's split up the method:

```
SetData<T>(T[], Int32, Int32)
```

- SetData - Method Name
- T - Any type you want (in this case, the XNA Color type)
- T[] - An array of the type you specified.
- Int32 x2 - Two Int32 values, namely Width and Height

So as the method tells you, you need to specify a type, and provide an array of said type. *However* you're providing it with an array of the type, so it expects a parameter that looks like T[][] (which is a compile-wise valid argument. It's an array of arrays of T). However when you only provide it a standard array, that's when it complains.

As long as your array contains as many entries as Width * Height (eg. array.Length == 1024x1024)

**To summarize**: Take a good hard look at the method structure when something doesn't make sense.

@Edit: Try doing something like this instead:

```
Texture2D myTexture = new Texture2D(this.GraphicsDevice, 1024, 1024);
Color[] theColors = new Color[myTexture.Width * myTexture.Height];

// Loop through each color object and define it.

myTexture.SetData<Color>(theColors);
```

Let me know if this works answers your question.

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more clear. What I meant was I am passing a `Color` array in like this: `Color[] theColor = new Color[1];  theColor[0] = Color.Black;  theTexture.SetData<Color>(theColor, startIndex, elementCount);` but no matter what I put in for startIndex and elementCount, I always get the error. I can however use `theTexture.SetData<Color>(colorArray);` where colorArray is an array of length (theTexture.Widht * theTexture.Height).

Comment: @applepie9883 I edited the reply to (hopefully) answer your actual question.

Comment: That's pretty much what I am doing currently, and it does work, but I want to use `SetData<T>(T[], Int32, Int32)` because I thought it would be faster than updating the entire image. (I have to update parts of the image each tick)

Comment: So if you want to change the entire 10th row of pixels to red, passing a 1024-sized array of colors, 1024*10 as index (because you need to skip the first 10 lines of pixels), and 1024 as Length, won't work. Is that what you're saying?

Comment: What I'm asking is: how do I use `SetData<T>(T[], int startIndex, int elementCount)` without throwing an error?

Comment: My guess is that the error is thrown because startIndex + elementCount goes outside the size of the texture, If that's not the case, I'm afraid I don't know